# Accessing multiple Json objects within Json objects using javax.json package in java

Tags: java, json

Hi i have this complex Json Object which I am trying to access some of the objects within the parent object, this is how it is printing out from the console. I am able to get the values in the parent/source object however I also need to access the customerLog. I am using javax.Json package and here is a snippet of my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public ArrayList<CustomerLog> getCustomers(String jsonString)
    {

        Reader stringReader = new StringReader(jsonString);
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(stringReader);
        JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
        reader.close();

        JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("Customer");

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size()-5; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("ID").toString());
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i+1).get("Username").toString());
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i+2).get("EmailAddress").toString());
            System.out.println(jsonArray.getJsonObject(i+4).get("CustomerLogs").toString());
            System.out.println(" ");
        } 
    return null;
    }
```

Response:

"7668"
"YASSIT"
"accounts@ausjetinks.com.au"
{"CustomerLog":[{"Notes":"Emailed Debbie to see how things are with her business.","LastContactedUTC":"2015-08-21 06:44:31","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2015-08-21 16:44:31","LastContactedLocal":"2015-08-21 16:44:31","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2015-09-18","LogID":"36195"},{"Notes":"Debbie replied saying how their Summer always v.quiet with school holidays but she expects things to pick up come September.","LastContactedUTC":"2015-08-24 02:05:47","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2015-08-24 12:05:47","LastContactedLocal":"2015-08-24 12:05:47","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"0000-00-00","LogID":"36197"},{"Notes":"Will recontact @ end-of-month","LastContactedUTC":"2015-09-18 01:54:41","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2015-09-18 11:54:41","LastContactedLocal":"2015-09-18 11:54:41","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2015-09-30","LogID":"36538"},{"Notes":"Sent Debbie email ","LastContactedUTC":"2015-09-30 06:07:40","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2015-09-30 16:07:40","LastContactedLocal":"2015-09-30 16:07:40","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2015-10-23","LogID":"36735"},{"Notes":"Sent Debbie email, replied saying she'd be placing an order next week","LastContactedUTC":"2017-01-12 02:25:45","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2017-01-12 12:25:45","LastContactedLocal":"2017-01-12 12:25:45","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2017-01-19","LogID":"39609"},{"Notes":"Emailed Debbie again to see how things going.","LastContactedUTC":"2017-02-07 01:45:06","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2017-02-07 11:45:06","LastContactedLocal":"2017-02-07 11:45:06","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2017-03-07","LogID":"39809"},{"Notes":"Emailed Debbie again to see if she's ready to place that order (....but we're low on a lot of clips:-(","LastContactedUTC":"2017-03-07 02:12:00","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2017-03-07 12:12:00","LastContactedLocal":"2017-03-07 12:12:00","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2017-04-11","LogID":"40168"},{"Notes":"Debbie emailed asking for Account to be re-activated: emailed Account Application form to her.","LastContactedUTC":"2018-04-23 23:15:32","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2018-04-24 09:15:32","LastContactedLocal":"2018-04-24 09:15:32","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2018-05-15","LogID":"43219"},{"Notes":"Debbie returned completed App. form - forwarded to Trudi","LastContactedUTC":"2018-04-24 05:06:34","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2018-04-24 15:06:34","LastContactedLocal":"2018-04-24 15:06:34","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"0000-00-00","LogID":"43222"},{"Notes":"New account application from filled in and signed with Canadian driver licences - due on invoice ","LastContactedUTC":"2018-04-26 03:27:52","FollowUpType":"Accounts","Status":"Completed","AllocatedTo":"Trudi Berquist","LastContacted":"2018-04-26 13:27:52","LastContactedLocal":"2018-04-26 13:27:52","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"0000-00-00","LogID":"43226"},{"Notes":"Contacted Debbie re: Order (all products now in stock)","LastContactedUTC":"2018-05-15 00:57:42","FollowUpType":"","Status":"Require Recontact","AllocatedTo":"Stephen Legge","LastContacted":"2018-05-15 10:57:42","LastContactedLocal":"2018-05-15 10:57:42","Customer":["Debbie Radchenko"],"DateRequiredFollowUp":"2018-05-22","LogID":"43274"}]}

Comment: Please share JSON and your code.

Comment: provide json you are getting

Comment: And also provide the json you are trying to parse. Thank you

Comment: Hi I have already provided the JSON coded and the JSON string I am trying to parse and get data from it. Can you please advise if you are not seeing it?

Comment: Hi Cristiano, the json the response

Comment: Hiren, the json is the response

Comment: coder-croc, the code is above the response, in CustomerLogs there is another object called CustomerLog which is a key to a Json Array. In that Json Array you have the listing of multiple objects with key-value pairs and json array as well. I have posted the snippet of the Json Object under response.